# Speaker noises when computer falls asleep. Doesn’t everyone have this problem? How do I fix it?

Tags: speakers, daw, setup, computer, production-mixing

**Setup**- computer > audio interface > monitor speakers

I want my computer to sleep occasionally so my external displays, etc aren’t draining power or blasting light at me while not in use. But when it does, my monitor speakers start buzzing or even making random siren noises (seriously, it’s very startling!)

Is there some other device I can put in between the interface and the speakers that will help? An amplifier maybe? Or will turning off the amp just make the speakers buzz again?

**Failed solutions:**

**Kill the power switch-** This works but it still makes a loud pop noise in the speakers like they’re going to blow up. It also means my displays are going to take longer to power back on later than if they were just asleep.

**Unplug the interface from my computer-** The speakers immediately buzz

**Turn off the speakers-** Ideal sound-wise, but not at all easy. These are pro monitor speakers (Dynaudio) so they’re not user-friendly: they both need to be turned off individually with a switch in the back so I would have to get up and reach around behind my desk twice every time I took a break from using my computer. I can't emphasize how not-an-option this is.

Comment: tbh, this isn't any more on-topic here than it was on music.se The answer is the same though, so I've moved it over.

Comment: Is there a music production section?

Comment: Not really. This SE covers music production, but this is not a 'production' issue, it's a simple hardware fail, to be expected when you sleep a computer wired to 400w of active speakers.

Comment: Might be a long shot, try changing the value of ‘Selective USB Suspend’ in the power options (this is for Windows, but other OSes should have such an option too, maybe with a different name).

Answer (score 1):

The "fix" is to get an interface that doesn't do this, or never let the machine sleep.

I have a similar problem with dynAudio BM6a's in that when the interface switches, the 400w bi-amps really don't like the bang. Fortunately mine don't whine or scream at me, just the bang, but it doesn't take many repetitions of ear-damagingly loud recurrence to teach you to switch them off ;)

I'd consider a volume pot after the pre-amp but I'd weigh that against what it might be doing to your $2000 sound.

BTW, most people don't get this issue because most people don't use powered monitors.

Comment: "most people don't use powered monitors" Is it true? I just looked at several internet stores, they offer several tens times more active monitor models than passive ones.

Comment: AFAIK that's a common question among people that does music production, as most of them use powered monitors. The fact is: if you're doing music production, you're used to do efforts since you care about your equipment, and it's possible that your computer consumes as much power as your monitors do. So, if you often leave your computer on even when you know that you're probably doing something else for a long time, there's a very small price to pay, and it's called "being more careful": just get the habit of switching off your speakers when you know you're probably not going to be back soon.

Answer (score 1):

Solved- I got a Mackie Big Knob passive($60) and it solved the issue..